# What is the use of multiple APNS certifcate for one App ID |

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new to iOS and developing push notification application. 
I am very much curious to know what is the significance of multiple APNS certificates associated with one App Id.

[image: Multiple APNS for a single APP ID]

As per my understanding one possible use case - If my application is receiving push notification from multiple vendors than at some point of time we want to stop allowing push notification from a specific vendor and we are using single APNS certificate than on revoking the certificate app will stop receiving push from all the vendors. 
If we are using different APNS certificate for all different vendors than we can revoke a specific vendor certificate and as a result app will only stop receiving push from the specific vendor.
Please correct me if I am on a wrong direction.

It will be great help if someone can explain the use of having multiple APNS certificate associated with one App Id.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Only 2 are allowed currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has only this use case If an application is receiving push notification from multiple vendors than at some point of time we want to stop allowing push notification from a specific vendor and we are using single APNS certificate than on revoking the certificate app will stop receiving push from all the vendors. If we are using different APNS certificate for all different vendors than we can revoke a specific vendor certificate and as a result app will only stop receiving push from the specific vendor. Please correct me if I am on a wrong direction.